# When a object calls another, which class should have that method?

Tags: uml

Suppose

[image]

Am I right to say `OnlinePortal` should have the method `initBooking(...)`, not Customer? I remember my TA saying that its Customer who should have the method (to ensure correct access rights or something)? but if thats the case, its possible that the method is duplicated many times?

Comment: Possibly worth migrating to SO?

Comment: @The Evil One, ops, I was wondering why u was suggesting to migrate from SO to SO, I only recently saw the message "migrated from askubuntu.com" ... I feel so retarded ... haha, must be too blur from too much homework

Comment: Heh.  Not a problem.  :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you're asking what that diagram symbolizes, then it means OnlinePortal has a method called initBooking that accepts to variables. If you're asking if that's how the system should be designed, then you'll need to provide .. a little more information. :)

I would expect OnlinePortal.initBooking to return a list of tickets or a recognizable error of some kind if it's not possible to accommodate the Customer.

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question. RE: Return type of boundary class. I am actually quite lost. I am familiar with MVC. But this "Boundary/Domain/DAL" thing puts me off. In a web application, the boundary is like a Controller/Router that routes request based on HTTPRequest params. So passing arguments like that seem wrong. Also the return type to the Customer will always be a HTTPResponse/HTML script? This diagram seem to imply Customer is a Class, if so does it need a `initBooking` to trigger `OnlinePortal.initBooking`, it seems to me now like it somehows trigger it